# Does $a\neq b$ imply $ka\neq kb$?

Tags: group-theory

Given an Abelian group $G$, I am asked to prove or give a counterexample to the following statement:

*If $a,b\in G$ are distinct, and both have the same order $l$, then $ka\neq kb$ for all $l\nmid k$.*

Obviously, to show that the statement is correct, its enough to prove it for all $0<k<l$. I Tried proving this with induction on $k$ like so: The statement is obviously true for $k=1$. Now assume that the statement holds for all integers $1<t<k$. Further, assume by negation that the statement does not hold for $k$, that is, we have $ka=kb$. Looking at $k$ and $l$ we see that if $k > l-k$ then we have $(l-k)a=(l-k)b$, which contradicts our assumption. If $k < l-k$ then we have $(l-2k)a=(l-2k)b$ which again contradicts our assumption.

This is where I got stuck, the last case is $k = l-k$ (or $l=2k$), and I can't seem to find a contradiction for this case.

Comment: I guess you mean here that $a,b\in G$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Hint: it's not true. (So try to find a counterexample!)

Comment: The question is bad.  If $k$ is an integer, then $G$ is not an arbitrary Abelian group.  What does it mean to multiply an element of a group by an integer?

Comment: @NovaDenizen it is common practice to write the operation of an abelian group additively, in which case we write $k a$ as a shorthand for $\underbrace{a+\cdots+a}_{k}$.

Comment: also, @downvoter, why... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $G=\mathbb Z_4$, and note that $3+3=1+1 \pmod 4$.

Answer (score 2):

Equivalently is like asking whether for distinct elements $a,b$ of same order $l$, the element $a-b$ has order smaller than $l$.
Using this you can find a counterexample. ($\mathbb{Z}_4$ works)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if $b = a+c$, where $c \notin \langle a \rangle$ has order $k$, with $k$ chosen so that $k \mid l$?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true:

Working in $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ the elements $\bar{1}$ and $\bar{3}$
have order $4$ but we have $2.\bar{1}=2.\bar{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Given $a\neq b$.  Assume there exists $k$ such that $ka = kb$.  Then $k^{-1}ka = k^{-1}kb$ and $a = b$, a contradiction.

Comment: what does $k^{-1}$ mean?

Comment: The question establishes that $k$ (as well as $a$ and $b$) is an element of $G$, a [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition).  All elements of groups have inverses, and $k^{-1}$ is the inverse of $k$, and $k^{-1}k = kk^{-1} = 1$.

Comment: no, $k$ is an integer, not an element of $G$.

Comment: The question is poorly specified.

Comment: @NovaDenizen although the OP did not write out "$k \in \mathbb Z$", it was pretty easy to infer from context, given that $\mathbb Z$ is the domain in which the symbols such as $l \nmid k$, $0 < k < l$ make sense.